# How Do I Disable Lightbox Pop Up From Loading On Certain Pages Of My WP Website

Tags: javascript, php

I have a Wordpress website and I recently added a lightbox that pops up after a few seconds of loading the site and collects emails. My email marketing provider is GetResponse. Basically, they gave me a script that I put in my website's footer so it loads the lighbox. Obviously, when it's set up like this, the lightbox loads on every single page of my website. So my question is how do I disable the lightbox from loading on certain pages of my website? I'd appreciate any input. This is the lightbox's code I added to my footer:

`<script type="text/javascript" src="https://app.getresponse.com/view_webform_v2.js?u=SXIds&webforms_id=9414305"></script>`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the WP function `is_page();` to only output the script on certain pages. This can be based on the title of the page, the id, etc. See more [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_page/).

```
<?php
    if(is_page( 'Home' )) {
        echo '<script type="text/javascript" src="https://app.getresponse.com/view_webform_v2.js?u=SXIds&webforms_id=9414305"></script>';
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution, add this to your page where you want to load the script. This prevents it from loading on other pages:

```
// You can replace 'Home' with a Page ID, title, slug, or array of such, if you want to
if (is_page( 'Home' ) ):
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://app.getresponse.com/view_webform_v2.js?u=SXIds&webforms_id=9414305"></script>
endif;
```

However, I think the proper way to do this, is to keep PHP logic outside of the HTML templates as much as possible. So instead of above mentioned solution, you might want to add this to your functions.php:

```
function load_scripts() {
    // You can change 'Home' with the Page ID, title, slug, or array of such, if you want to
    if ( is_page( 'Home' ) ) {
        wp_enqueue_script( 'GetResponse', 'https://app.getresponse.com/view_webform_v2.js?u=SXIds&webforms_id=9414305', false );
        // here you can enqueue more js / css files 
    }
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_scripts' );
```

`wp_enqueue_scripts` is an action which will be loaded by Wordpress, by default. You can create your own action, but in that case you have to load it yourself, for example:

```
// Create my own action 'load_my_scripts', which executes the 'load_scripts' function
add_action( 'load_my_scripts', 'load_scripts' );
// Load (or execute) the action 
do_action( 'load_my_scripts' );
```